# Can you intercept voice chat messages on Mesibo so that it can be routed to google cloud services for translating to another language

Tags: text-to-speech, chatbot, speech-to-text, google-translate, mesibo

I am new to Mesibo,  I have been playing with google cloud services for language translation, however, I have read elsewhere that it does not scale. At the moment I am not interested in scaling, but I was wondering if Google cloud translation services will play well with Mesibo chat

Comment: I have no idea how google translation service works but you can add a listener to Mesibo to get all the messages, which you can then translate using whatever services you are using. I can help further if you add more information.

Comment: Thanks... that's what I wanted to know.I am thinking of implementing a chat service that translates texts between users. In this context, the two users speak two different languages.  So users type in their native languages, but it gets translated to the recipient's language for delivery

Comment: Not sure about your target audience but sounds like a very cool idea, for both, personal and businesses (support/helpdesk).